# How do I test belongs_to associations with Rails 6 and RSpec 4.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, associations, ruby-on-rails-6

I’m upgrading from Rails 4.2 to 6.  I'm also using FactoryBot 6.2.0.  I have this model

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, inverse_of: :book
    …
  validates :model, presence: true, unless: -> { author.check_vwf? }
```

I have an RSpec (rspec-rails 4.1.2 ) test where I want to test an association …

```
describe Book do

    …
  it { should belong_to :author }
```

But running this test fails with the below error.  It appears that the “validates” method is getting run and the instance being constructed has no “belongs_to” association, but that is exactly what I’m trying to test …

```
 Failure/Error: validates :model, presence: true, unless: -> { author.check_vwf? }
 
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `check_vwf?' for nil:NilClass
```

Something about upgrading my Rails caused this test to suddenly fail.  What’s the proper way with the given version of Rails and RSpec to test an association?

Comment: Please provide the code for the Books factory. Also, is there a book object created in the test?

Comment: THe "..." are just other "it" association checks.  There is no explicit call to create an instance of the object.

Comment: @Dave can you please update your question with both models. Seems something wrong there with association and `inverse_of`

Comment: can you provide details on your factories and how you used them in the specs? have you used factory bot at all?

Answer (score 1):

Shoulda matcher is defining a [subject by default](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers#on-the-subject-of-subject), but this subject creates a problem for your case. You could try adding the following at the start of the test file to override the default one.

```
let!(:author) { create(:author) }
subject { create(:book, author: author) }
```

Assuming you have defined the author and book factories.

Comment: Gave that a try but no dice.  I don't think the "should belong_to" tests are using the subject I define.

Comment: what is your subject?

Answer (score 1):

I think your issues could be related to your association.
Since Rails 5 the `belongs_to` association is required by default.

If you want to be able to create records without the association you need to add the following:

```
 belongs_to :author, inverse_of: :book, optional: true
```